# How to pass a pointer as an array argument?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, argument-passing, function-declaration

I have a third-party library, which has a function delared as follows:

```
void foo(const void* input, char output[1024]);
```

If I write something like this:

```
char* input = "Hello";
char  output[1024];
foo(input, output); // OK
```

But I don't want to declare such a big array on stack (that would be very dangerous in OS kernel environment). So I have to do something like this:

```
char* input      = "Hello";
char* output_buf = new char[1024];
foo(input, output_buf); // Compiler Error C2664
```

I cannot change the implementation of foo. How should I do?

=================

The problem has been resolved. My real code is like this:

```
char* input      = "Hello";
void* output_buf = new char[1024];
foo(input, output_buf); // Compiler Error C2664
```

conversion from void* to char* is not implicitly accepted by the standard. So the following code works:

```
char* input      = "Hello";
void* output_buf = new char[1024];
foo(input, (char*)output_buf); // OK
```

Comment: what about input's declaration?

Comment: input has nothing to do with this problem. So I omitted it.

Comment: Using `new` can be even more dangerous "in OS kernel environment" (it can throw.) Use `malloc`, and cast.

Comment: @xmllmx: I think you're wrong about that.  You're assuming input has nothing to do with your problem because you do not understand how `output` is actually passed to `foo`.  However, `output` is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: @xmllmx To the contrary, declaring a large object had better be on the stack, unless you are sure that your stack size limit does not allow that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333443/c-object-instantiation

Comment: Incidentally, @xmllmx, what is the **full** error message (parameter number, type), and are `char` the actual types the real code uses?

Comment: @PoP: if an object is large the rule of thumb is that it goes on the heap to avoid risking a stack overflow even in reasonable scenarios; of course an object is considered "large" or "small" in comparison to the stack size - e.g. on a "normal" user-mode 1 MB stack 1 KB is usually "small" (unless there's recursion), but in other situations it may not be so.

Comment: That's totally due to my carelessness. I have edited the original post.

Comment: @xmllmx: also, remember that string literals are of type `const char *`, not just `char *` (there's a deprecated implicit conversion, but it will usually just give you needless headaches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `output`.  In reality your function does not take an array as you cannot pass arrays to functions.  It receives a pointer to char.  This would work as well:

```
void foo(char f[1024])
{
    // blah
}

int main() {
    char c1[1];
    foo(c1);  // works!

    char *c2 = new char[27];
    foo(c2);  // works!

    delete [] c2; 
}
```

That code will compile, and it does so because the function receives a pointer, that is all.  So, the problem is with your first argument, `input`.  It's type must be wrong.  Look at your error message more closely and/or show us the declaration of `input`.

Comment: Forgot to delete `c`... :)

Comment: @David:...ok, fair enough.  Of course, the next person is going to complain that I am manually managing memory and will yell at me until I use a vector.

Comment: @EdS.: that's exactly the fear I had when I wrote the example in my answer :)

Comment: While at it, you also forgot to catch `std::bad_alloc`. Ooops! ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's strange, since in C++ any function argument of array type is actually considered of pointer type, i.e. the "real" function signature seen by the compiler is

```
void foo(const void* input, char* output);
```

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” [...] is adjusted to be “pointer to T” (C++11, [dcl.fct], ¶5)

Most importantly, your code *does* work, as you can see [here](http://ideone.com/EIX75z); are you sure that your "narrowed down" example actually reflects the problem you are seeing? Probably the problem lies in the type of another parameter.

Comment: +1 I concur with this answer, except to note the subtle nuance of the standard, which in-reality identifies the specific *leading* array subscript as the degenerate pointer. This becomes important with multi-subscript arrays. I.e. `foo(char ar[10][20]` degenerates to `foo(char (*ar)[20])` (or `foo(char ar[][20])` if you prefer). This allows you to pass a `char[2][20]` but *not* a `char[10][10]` to said function.